# Using result from Scalas "fromURL" throws Exception

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get some webpages using Scala's scala.io.Source object. Getting the iterator works fine but i cant do anything with it without getting an exception:

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://google.com")
res0: scala.io.BufferedSource = non-empty iterator

scala> scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://google.com").length
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:338)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcI$sp$1.apply$mcI$sp(BufferedSource.scala:38)
at scala.io.Codec.wrap(Codec.scala:64)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1.apply$mcI$sp(BufferedSource.scala:38)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:38)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:38)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.next(Iterator.scala:150)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$25.hasNext(Iterator.scala:562)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:400)
at scala.io.Source.hasNext(Source.scala:238)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
at scala.io.Source.foreach(Source.scala:181)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.size(TraversableOnce.scala:104)
at scala.io.Source.size(Source.scala:181)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.length(Iterator.scala:1071)
at scala.io.Source.length(Source.scala:181)
at .<init>(<console>:8)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:11)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So as you can see obtaining the buffer works, i can do something with it

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://google.com").next
res7: Char = <
```

But it seems I cant iterate over it.

I'm using scala v 2.9.2 but the problem recurs in 2.11.2 as well. Further I'm running

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an encoding issue here.

The Encoding needed for interpreting the response is `latin1`, also known as `ISO-8859-1`.

Use `Source.fromURL("url")("encoding")` to solve your problem.

```
 Source.fromURL("http://google.com")("ISO-8859-1").mkString
 res4: String =
 <!doctype html><html itemscop
```

A little background: When no encoding is given in a `http request` the standard behaviour is to retun everything encoded in Latin-1. 
For in depth info see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt